# Setting up SSH Server

Tags: server, ssh, openssh

I discovered the joys of ssh through school. I can connect to the school computers writing username@siegbahn.it.uu.se, which prompts me for password and bam, I'm in. **No** setup was necessary on my part.

Anyway, I'd like it to be possible to connect to my main computer this way as well, i.e. if I'm on my laptop and would like to run stuff on my desktop computer I could just write ssh username@mydesktop or something and then I'm in. As far as I gather, I need to set up an ssh server.

I've googled some articles on setting up an ssh server and trying it out on my laptop (for now), [here's](http://www.htpcbeginner.com/install-ssh-server-on-ubuntu-1204/) one such article and [here's](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openssh-server.html) another. As for the first link, I've done all the parts stated except the AllowUsers part, which puzzles me. What would a username look like? There's a macbook next to me, in the terminal it says Petes-macbook-pro; is that the username or what? Also, if Pete wants to connect to me, what would he write? I never gave out or even defined a nice "address" such as the above @siegbahn.it.uu.se.

As stated I've been trying to find answers to this but all the articles about ssh seem to assume that you've done steps 1-10 and only guide you on steps 11-20.

What I've done:
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
in sshd_config, change port number and set PermitRootLogin to no.

Thanks for your advice.

EDIT: Connection at home is a cable from the wall into a router. Fiber optic I guess? I live in an apartment but the Internet is not provided by the apartment. Well, the jack in the wall is...

Answer (score 5):

Don't get fancy to start. Before fiddling around with setttings, changing the port, I'd make sure it works as intended. If you can, put everything back the way it was and see if it works. I don't think any user configuration is necessary to get the basic thing working.  You don't need to enable ssh for particular users.  Just do the basics, then add modifications later. Maybe you could remove the package (and settings) and reinstall.

After that:

1. Is the sshd server process running.

On Ubuntu systems, installing the package typically starts the ssh process that answers requests from other systems.

Check if sshd is running. In shell, run

```
ps aux | grep ssh
```

I see this, which means it is running:

```
root   1144  0.0  0.0  67824  5448 ? Ss   Dec06   0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

If it is not running, again, I'm surprised because the packaging scripts will usually turn that on in Ubuntu.  You can turn it on.  The steps are written out on the basic page. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring

2. Check if you can log in FROM THE SAME system

Open a terminal, and try to ssh into your own account. Try

```
ssh localhost
```

You can also try "ssh yourname@your.ip.number" as well. If you can't do it from your own system, then you know the ssh service is not turned on or configured correctly.

3. Bring your laptop and sit next to the trouble server system.  If ssh works on same system, but not from other systems, then you have a different problem to find.  If you have been fiddling with firewalls and such, then you've probably outsmarted yourself. I sometimes have settings in /etc/hosts.deny and /etc/hosts.allow that are contradictory.

You can monitor your system logs on the server while you try to log in from your laptop.  Sometimes you can see the trouble. I think the right file to watch is /var/log/auth.log. That may give you some hints.

You don't mention what firewall settings you might have, but I would turn off the firewall entirely for a few minutes to test out the ssh server. Of course, you turn that back on.

In my experience, this is one way in which running Ubunutu is a little bit more frustrating than other linuxes, so be patient.

After all that, then go someplace else to try. If there is  trouble

4. It may be that the network administrators in your system are blocking access. Administrators at my place have become very strict and now filter all incoming ssh requests, NO MATTER WHAT PORT!  If you are in that unhappy situation, you will need to get the administrators to set up a VPN for you.

Or it may be your own configuration has blocked your access. Sometimes you can see that while tracking auth.log or "dmesg" output more generally. If you get to that stage, you should write back. Somebody here who is better at iptables will help you, I expect.

In summary, don't start changing settings until you know what works out of the box.  Later on, after it works, fiddle with settings. Change one thing at a time.  I always turn on X11 forwarding. You were wise to change the root password setting in /etc/sshd_config. Changing the port seems, well, not highly beneficial.

Comment: Thank you! Points 1 and 2 worked fine. As for point 3, that's partly my problem: how do I even attempt to connect Pete's laptop that's next to me, to the computer where I'm trying to set this all up? Googling "my ip" gives that both computers have the same IP. I tried ssh ip@ip from Pete's computer and it timed out. Should I write petescomp@ip, or what do I write for username?

Comment: I forgot; Regarding firewall settings they are whatever is the default, if any.

Comment: @ErikVesterlund, if you and Pete are both on the same private local segment behind a NAT'ing router, then you use the *local* IP addresses to connect from one to the other.  To see the local addresses of each machine issue `ip -4 addr` on the ubuntu box and `ifconfig` on the Mac.  Then on the mac you should be able to `ssh username@${IP_OF_UBUNTU_BOX}`, and similarly to ssh from the ubuntu machine to the Mac.

Comment: Great! From ip -4 addr I get three addresses, I tried all and they gave different responses; connection refused, operation timed out, and permission denied. A bit hard to troubleshoot. And I still don't know, what would Pete's username be? In his terminal it says Petes-macbook-pro, is that it, or what is it?

Comment: @ErikVesterlund, home networks *typically* use local addresses in the 192.168.x.y range.  127.0.0.1 should show up as your `lo` interface (loopback), which is only for internal connections, not to connect to the machine from another machine.   You don't need Pete's username, you need the username of any account existing on the machine.  If there is an account `erik` on the ubuntu machine, for example, then `ssh erik@${IP_ADDR}`.  You can always add another account for Pete, but adding additional users is a matter of system management, not `ssh` per se.

Comment: No wait I think I got it. Like, my username on this comp is erik, so I should try ssh erik@ip, and that will prompt me for my computer password, right?

Comment: Calm down a minute. You are able to ssh into the target if you are logged into it. Right?  In there, run "/sbin/ifconfig" and it shows you the IP numbers. Look for IPV4 numbers that might be the target's number. SSH into that number.   In your first post, you said the target machine was in the office, not another laptop at home.  Where it is will affect the answer.  I was assuming you are on a router at "work" where machine addresses are "real internet addresses". ie, not ones that start with 192.168... If your admin does not let your IP be available, then you are in  problem category 4.

Comment: Sorry, reached limit on typing.  If you get "/sbin/ifconfig" output from target machine, you can usually tell from IP if it is a publicly available address.  Usually, at my work, the machines are set up that way, but I have heard of places where they are all hidden behind a firewall router, and no incomings are allowed.  If your work machine is at 192.168.xx, that's a bad sign. Anyway, from inside the network run "ping xxx.xxx.xx.xx" for your IP address. If it anwsers, good, then go outside network and try same. If no answer, then you are firewalled.

Comment: /sbin/ifconfig is not legible (with nano, at least). There has been no mention of an office or work, I have only mentioned my desire to be able to ssh to my desktop at home like I'm able to ssh with the school computers.
I was not aware that I had an admin at all, unless that is CS lingo for ISP. My machines are not set up in any particular manner, I am not a sysadmin or even computer savvy. On that note, I don't know if the response to ping is good or not, it says no packets were lost which sounds good, but I don't know.

Comment: To ssh to your desktop at home, please edit your question and [edit]( https://askubuntu.com/posts/859557/edit) your question above and provide information about how you connect to the Internet from home. i assume you have a router and a modem to connect to the Internet service provider using DSL, Cable, or some other means. If your live in an apartment and the Internet is provided by the apartment, then things will be complicated.

Comment: I do not mean to open /sbin/ifconfig as if it were a file. Run it, it is a program. It shows the IP address. Example, within my home, where I have a wireless router, I get "wlp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.110  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255".  See where it says "inet".  That is the number I'd use to connect "into" this system. Test that in my step 3.  Suppose that works. Then to figure out step 4, open web browser from target system and browse to "whatismyip.com".  From inside home router, that will tell the IP you have now.

Comment: If you go outside home, you want to ssh into the place reported by "whatismyip.com", but you will fail because your incoming is blocked at the router.  That's where other fellow's answer is necessary. Your home router has to be configured to  pass along the ssh connection to your laptop.  Warning: If you home does not have static (fixed) IP assigned by ISP, you will see a new IP sometimes when your router restarts (after power failure). Thi smeans @Organic Marble read your question correctly in the first place, and I did not understand.

Comment: @pauljohn32 Connecting to the inet IP and the whatismyIP yields the same effect, operation timed out.

Comment: Just to be clear: you open a web browser and go to "https://www.whatismyip.com" and you get nothing?  That makes me suspect your internet is not working at all.  Or your router has some kind of anonymity feature that I've never heard of.

Comment: Depends what you mean by nothing. Do I get an IP, yes. What happens if I ssh to that IP? Stated at least twice in this thread.

Comment: Honestly, your answers are so vague I can't guess what you are doing or what's not working.  You are in Step 3 of my answer.  Maybe you should close this question, make a new one. First,  in the SSH server, run "sudo tail -f /var/log/auth.log" to monitor requests.   Then log in from account in that system, watch what happens. Then log in from laptop within same network.  Then Start a new question on the ONE problem you are trying to solve.  Give detail, which IP you are using, etc.  From above, I can't even tell if "/sbin/ifconfig" worked for you.

Comment: The answers are not vague. On dec 13 you said that the IP to ssh into is the one given by ifconfig, and you also talked about the IP given by whatismyip.com. I replied that using either of those (from this one may draw the conclusion that ifconfig worked for me) has the same effect, namely "operation timed out". You then asked if I get nothing; well, in my post immediately preceding that question I had already answered that, namely that what I get is "operation timed out". Explicitly, "ssh user@theIPgivenbyifconfig" and "ssh user@theIPgivenbywhatismyip" is the same: "operation timed out"

Comment: I take abuse like this for a living. I suppose vague is in the eye of the beholder.   You have a misconfigured server or router.  It is important to start new question because in there you can include full details on server config.  Show everybody the output of /sbin/ifconfig from both systems and the auth log when you try to log in.   I suspect your port settings on server are wrong on server.  Suspect same on router.  Post a a new specific question WITH FULL DETAILS about what is wrong, and somebody else might try to help.

Answer (score 2):

Everything you need to know is on the Ubuntu wiki.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring

To address some of your specific questions:

You will need to forward a port in your router to your server, to allow access from outside your home network.  Some suggest using a different port than the standard, to minimize the number of bot attacks.  You can still use the standard port on your server, which is recommended. Simply forward the non standard port in the router to the standard port in your server.  You would then access it by `ssh servername:nonstandardportnumber`

IMHO it is more secure to set up key based logins than to allow userid/password logins. This topic is covered in the wiki I linked to.

Comment: The answers may well be in that link but I don't recognize them. How does one forward a port in the router? I will keep X11forwarding yes, but there is no AllowTcpForwarding entry, there is a TCPKeepAlive though?
As for ssh servername, that's just my problem, what is the servername? How do I set it? Again, the answer may be in your link but if so I don't recognize it. (Not a CS guy.)

Comment: Don't get carried away with this yet.  It assumes you are in a small home network and you do control the router.  I'm not sure this applies to the problem you described.  I can explain author's idea, though. All computers inside a home router (that has 1 IP address) are behind the router. The router has an address that is available to outside, but incoming SSH connections die at that address. However, the router can be configured to pass along the incoming SSH to a particular internal ID.  In the original post, I had the idea you were at work with a target machine that is on the internet.

Comment: If your machine does not have a publicly available address, and you don't control the router setup, then you are stuck unless admin will help.  On the other hand, if you are in a home network, you can usually find settings in the ROUTER software to give incoming connections on port 22 (maybe other ports) to a particular laptop.  I used to have D-link router and they made that super easy.  Now I have a router that makes it super difficult. Key point here is that this is a ROUTER configuration, not an Ubuntu setting.  Router has to allow the SSH messages through to the target server.